I don't understand how ( is abelian iff ()=g² is a homomorphism), when the group operation could be addition.
I must be misunderstanding something.
If G is Zn, isn't (ℎ)=()(ℎ) equivalent to (g+h)² = g² + h², which is not always true. But addition is commutative and Zn is abelian.

The statement is for groups written multiplicatively. If the group is written additively, then the map sends $a$ to $a+a$ (but you wouldn't normally use $+$ to denote a group operation that is not known to be commutative, absent some very specific circumstances).

And if you are looking at $Z_n$ as a group, then there is no "multiplication", there is only addition.

You're conflating the notations.   In addition,  it's $\varphi (g+h)=2(g+h)=(g+h)+(g+h)=g+g+h+h=2g+2h=\varphi (g)+\varphi (h).$

We sometimes get sloppy with our notation.
When we write $g^2$ we really mean $g\star g$ where $\star$ is our group operator.  If the group operation is addition then $g^2$ is $g+g.$
If the group operator is function composition, then $g^2$ is the function composed with itself.
There is only one group operation.  If addition is our group operator, then multiplication has not been defined.  It is not until we get to rings, that we get an addition and a multiplication operation (or operations analogous to addition and multiplication).

This justifies your having more points than me.  Remember:   even one more point means you're more intelligent.

If $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$ is an abelian group, we want to show that $\phi(g) = 2g$ is a homomorphism. In $\mathbb{Z}_n$, we usually work with addition to show it is a group homomorphism, and not multiplication.
Let $g, h \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, then
\begin{equation*}
\phi(g + h) = 2(g + h) = (g + h) + (g + h) = 2g + 2h = \phi(g) + \phi(h)
\end{equation*}
so $\phi$ is a group homomorphism.

The symbol used for the operation is in principle irrelevant.   As art points out, plus tends to be reserved for abelian ones (since normal addition is commutative), and if you're looking at say $\Bbb Z_n$ with addition $0$ is your identity;   whereas if you go with multiplicative notation, it becomes $1. $
Technically for this you need an isomorphism.  You'll learn more about it.    But you can use $\chi(g^i)=i,$ where $g$ is a generator.
For fun, since you actually do have the option,  let's do this one with multiplicative notation.
Then,  $\varphi (g)=g^2.$  We check $\varphi (gh)=(gh)^2=gh\cdot gh=gghh=g^2h^2=\varphi(g)\varphi (h),$ where we used that $\Bbb Z_n$ is abelian.
